# Given this example, what do I benefit from the poll design, compared to using multiple threads or processes instead?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, sockets, multiprocessing

Recently I've been learning socket programming and finally I found some good examples from [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#poll).

There's a chat server example using `poll` under the `poll` [section](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#poll).

**Code**:

[charsever.c](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/pollserver.c) (chat server receives clients message and send messages to all the other clients)

---

After I read the code line by line and fully understand the example, I suddenly realize how clever and neat the design is.

Basically, it uses a `poll` to monitor everything, the server listening socket `accept` for new incoming TCP connections and all the existing TCP sockets. No extra threads or processes are needed.

---

Then I started to ask myself:

It seems that I can use multiple processes (or multiple threads if that's too complicated) to achieve the same effect. Take the chat server as example, the design can be:

- main process handle new incoming TCP connections and add new connection sockets to a global array `all_sockets`.
- for each new connection in main process, `fork` a child process to block, write something like:

```
    //pseudo-code
    int bytes_from_client;

    while(true){
        if( (bytes_from_client = recv(xx,xx,xx,xx)) <= 0 ){
            if(bytes_from_client == 0){
                client_shutdown();
            } else {
                error_handle();
            }
        } else {
            //recv data from client and send messages to all the other clients
            for(int i = 0; i < all_sockets[x]; i++){
                send(xx,xx,xx,xx);
            }
        }
    }
```

- Ok then I need to handle some synchronization issues for global variables. Use `mutex` or something else. (hard part)

---

So now for the questions:

1. What exactly do I benefit from the `poll` design pattern, compared to the mulithreads one that I laterly described? No need to handle synchronization? Only this 1 advantage?
2. (A more generic but meaningful question) Is this design pattern made by `poll` like functions (`select`, `epoll`) that makes them so different/unique and great? (I am a newbie and I asked this because I've seen so many people saying how great and significant the `poll` family functions are. But they never tell why, neither give examples or comparisons. )

Answer (score 2):

One basic reason why a simple `select()` loop works so very well is that network packets always arrive one-at-a-time and, compared to the blinding speed of any CPU, very slowly.  There simply isn't any advantage to a more complicated arrangement.

Often, one thread or process is dedicated to handling the network connection ... polling for incoming packets and sending outgoing messages on behalf of everyone.  (I've heard it called "the telegrapher.")  It then uses queues to distribute the work to a stable of "worker-bee" processes, which retrieve requests on one queue, then post the outgoing answers to another queue which is also listened-to by the telegrapher.

Sometimes, the telegrapher simply listens for connection-requests, places the handles on a queue, and the worker bees open the connection and do the networking themselves.  But, once again, they can simply use polling and it works just fine.  Even the fastest communication line is orders of magnitude slower than a CPU.

Comment: I really like epoll or select for some network server use cases. But I would not say that network packets arrive slowly, especially on modern 10 GBit and even 100 GBit NICs. One extreme example is user-space networking, for example Intel DPDK. One cache miss in your receiving loop will blow performance out of the water.